# Google analytics angularjs directive for track events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I am trying to implement a Directive to track events (such a click event) for GA, but for some reason the directive is getting fired with any click event on the application, 
here is my code I am using Phonegap GA plugin by the way:

```
myApp.directive('bcaTrackEvent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function ($rootScope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            $rootScope.gaPlugIn.trackEvent(function(){}, function(){}, element.type, "Click", element.name, 1);
        }
    };
});
```

Here is where I am using it:

```
<div id="layout">
    <p class="blank"></p>
    <p class="logo"></p>
    <p class="blank"></p>
    <div id="signOptions">
        <a ng-href="#/SignIn"><input bca-track-event name="signIn" class="bigbutton" type="button" value="{{'_SignIn_' | localizeIt}}" /></a>
        <a ng-href="#/SignUp"><input class="bigbutton" type="button"  value="{{'_SignUp_' | localizeIt}}"/></a>
        <p class="blank"></p>
        <a class="tourlink" href="#/TakeTour" data-localize-it="_TakeTour_"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a working example using plnkr.co or something similar?

Comment: Shouldn't you be binding the click event of the element where the directive is applied?

Comment: @Javito, I have a query..what are these parameters `function(){}, function(){}` inside `trackEvent` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link function of the directive will always be run when the directive is first added, so that's why your code is running each time. You need to add a click event handler inside the link function of the directive, and that will be the bit that only runs on click.

```
myApp.directive('bcaTrackEvent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function ($rootScope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            element.on("click", function() {
                 $rootScope.gaPlugIn.trackEvent(function(){}, function(){}, element.type, "Click", element.name, 1);
            });

        }
    };
});
```

BTW, the parameters passed to the link function are always the scope, element, attributes and controller. You've written $rootScope as a parameter, but what's actually doing is just renaming normal scope as $rootScope inside the directive. In this situation the scope inheritance means it's working anyway, but I think you'd be better renaming the variable to just `scope` though to stop potential confusion.

If you need real $rootScope, inject it into the directive itself not the link function, e.g.

```
myApp.directive('bcaTrackEvent', function ($rootScope) {
```

Comment: I have a query..what are these parameters `function(){}, function(){}` inside `trackEvent` function.